# Smart Wizard Jquery plugin Square progress not working

Tags: html, jquery, css, step, smart-wizard

I added smart wizard to my page for a step plugin.
But the progress is not working on top nav bar.
Line doesn't appear
I added "square" and added the necessary css to the code
but not working

[image]

```
selected: 0,
// Initial selected step, 0 = first step
theme: 'square',
// Theme for the wizard, related css need to include for other than default theme
justified: true,
// Nav menu justification. true/false
autoAdjustHeight: true,
// Automatically adjust content height
backButtonSupport: true,
// Enable the back button support
enableUrlHash: true,
// Enable selection of the step based on url hash
transition: {
  animation: 'fade',
  // Animation effect on navigation, none|fade|slideHorizontal|slideVertical|slideSwing|css(Animation CSS class also need to specify)
  speed: '400',
  // Animation speed. Not used if animation is 'css'
  easing: '',
  // Animation easing. Not supported without a jQuery easing plugin. Not used if animation is 'css'
  prefixCss: '',
  // Only used if animation is 'css'. Animation CSS prefix
  fwdShowCss: '',
  // Only used if animation is 'css'. Step show Animation CSS on forward direction
  fwdHideCss: '',
  // Only used if animation is 'css'. Step hide Animation CSS on forward direction
  bckShowCss: '',
  // Only used if animation is 'css'. Step show Animation CSS on backward direction
  bckHideCss: '' // Only used if animation is 'css'. Step hide Animation CSS on backward direction

},
```

Comment: Anyone? I really need help on this

Answer (score 0):

actually im facing the same problem. I already solve the issue. The problem is i forget to add the "nav-progress" on "ul" tag. I hope the problem is the same like you.

```
        <ul class="nav nav-progress">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#step-1">
                    <div class="num">1</div>
                    Title 1
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#step-2">
                    <span class="num">2</span>
                    Title 2
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```